# Issue with scrollview

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

Following is the android layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/svb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="450dp" 

    android:isScrollContainer="true" 
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numColumns="2"


android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
> 
</GridView>



 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/rl2"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rl3"
>
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
     android:src="@drawable/total"         
    /> 
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalscore"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/total"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/rl4"

>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    >
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RATE THIS APP"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


           />
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >

<Button
            android:id="@+id/paid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BUY AD FREE VERSION"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"


            />

   </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>



   </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

I want the scroll to encompass the whole layout but it covers only the gridview. Only one item of the gridview is shown and to see others I have to scroll. The views below the gridview are seen all the time. How to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting android:layout_height="wrap_content"  in the first LinearLayout just after the scrollView

Comment: Now all views are visible but there is no scrollbar.bottom two buttons are squeezed into the screen instead of flowing out below with a visible scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="450dp"> <----replace this with wrap_content

<LinearLayout ...>        

   // ADD ALL OTHER LAYOUT HERE

       <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalscore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total" <---- you forget PLUS sign here
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this distorts the layout. the buttons below gridview are not visible. in gridview only 3 rows are visible, other rows have to be scrolled

Comment: see my edited answer correct this `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total"`

Comment: that has not changed the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tablelayout within ScrollView. Here is a sample code that works

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp">
        <!--Month Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select Month"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinneryr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field1 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ERYTHROCYTE"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ERYTHROCYTE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field2 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/HAEMOGLOBIN"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/HAEMOGLOBIN"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field3 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/PCV"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PCV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field4 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/RDW"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/RDW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field5 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MCV"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MCV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field6 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MCH"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MCH"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"

                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>

        <!--Field7 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MCHC"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/MCHC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field8 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/LEUCOCYTECOUNT"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/LEUCOCYTECOUNT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field9 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/PLATELETS"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PLATELETS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field10 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NEUTROPHILS"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/NEUTROPHILS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field11 Combo Box-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/EOSINOPHILS"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EOSINOPHILS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Field12 Combo Box-->

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/LYMPHOCYTES"
                android:textColor="#0c0b0b"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/LYMPHOCYTES"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </TableRow>
        <!-- Button :Start here-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnViewAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view_all" />
        </TableRow>

            <!--<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/delete" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnShowInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/show_info" />
        </TableRow>-->

<!--        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20sp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnModify"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/modify" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view" />




           <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShowInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/show_info" >
        </TableRow-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvValues"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]